# How loop 2 setIntervals without creating multiple requests?

Tags: javascript

```
function Test(time) {
    i = 1;
    fun1 = setInterval(function () {
      if (i >= 1 && i <= 10) {
        $('.class.' + i).children('.BUTTON').click();
      }
    }, time * i);
    fun2 = setInterval(function () {
      if (result > 0 && i < 10) {
        console.log('The number is ' + i);
        i++;

      } 
      else if (result < 0) {
        console.log('Sorry at ' + i + ' point you fell in the hole');
        clearInterval(fun2);
        stats.loss++;
        $('.loss').text(stats.loss);
        console.log('Number of fell are ' + stats.loss);
      } else {
        console.log('Exited from maze');
        clearInterval(fun);
        clearInterval(fun2);
        stats.wins++;
        $('.wins').text(stats.wins);
        console.log('Number of wins are ' + stats.wins);
        $('#START').click();
      }
    }, time * 1.3);
  }
```

Last time I asked about making the if's in a for holding the i, loved it, then, I had the idea of checking the result of the path, showed in this case as points. And this way works great, problem is, what if I want to create an "infinite loop" to check if in the long run my character would be a winner or loser?
Solutions I tried: for,while,do while, they ends up requestin thousands of requests to the server.
tried with A main set interval, but somehow it just creates parallel requests and even If I do clearInterval(masterloop); it just activate the test again and again, speeding up and clicks only the start/reset level button.

Comment: That `i` is global so that may lead to bugs.

Comment: What is making requests to the server in that code?

Comment: the setIntervals repeats themselves too fast and they are like in a loop of their own

Comment: Well what is the value of time?

Comment: 2000 is the value I use for it, I think it's an accettable amount.